# Excel VBA: Loop from largest value and check for conditions

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to write a Excel VBA code which do the following:

1. Find the largest value in a column
2. Check 2 conditions for the largest value:

   - If satisfy the 2 conditions, pull the largest value
   - If not satisfy the 2 conditions, go to the 2nd largest value
3. Repeat the above steps until we find one value which satisfy the 2 conditions

For example (I have thousands of data and multiple sheets, this is just to simplify),

Col A   Col B   Col C   Col D

5   0   0   Apple

10  1   0   Apple

15  (-1)    0   Orange

20  0   0   Apple

1. Largest value is 20 in column A
2. Check 2 conditions:

   - Look for non-zero and non-negative in either col B or col C
   - Col D: equal to Apple

The output should be equal to 10 (row 2)

I am not sure how to do this. Please point me to the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should get the highest value in Column A:

```
Sub get_max() 
    Dim vMax As Variant 

    vMax = Application.WorksheetFunction _ 
    .Max(Range("A:A")) 

    MsgBox vMax 

End Sub
```

If no one else replies, I'll see what I can do about finding the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Why not an excel formula?

```
=MAX(IF(B1:B5>0,A1:A5,IF(C1:C5>0,A1:A5)))
```

[image]

If you still want VBA then see this

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("=MAX(IF(B1:B5>0,A1:A5,IF(C1:C5>0,A1:A5)))")
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible for the formula to check for apple, orange in column D without VBA? I don't want to do 1 by 1 in a column tho. Is it possible to have 1 formula to do all the checks for me including finding a substring in a string? Thanks!!

Comment: What do you exactly want to check? Let's say Col B and Col C are not there.

Comment: Check 2 things:
1. either col B or Col C greater than 0 (which your formula does)
2. Col D is equal to apple

so then it return 10

Comment: Can you explain more? Check what?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying more

Comment: Like this? `=MAX(IF(B1:B5>0,A1:A5,IF(C1:C5>0,IF(D1:D5="Apple",A1:A5))))`

Comment: Hi your formula works like a charm!! However, when I try to enter into VBA. It gave me an error. The error message says "Unable to set FormulaArray to Range Class". Do you mind helping me to troubleshoot it? **Workbooks(PreviousWS(i, 1)).Sheets("ImportApples").Range("D13").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(F15:F100>0,D15:D100,IF(G15:G100>0,D15:D100,IF(H15:H100>0,D15:D100,IF(I15:I100>0,D15:D100,IF(J15:J100>0,IF(FIND(OR(" & """Apple""" & "," & """Orange""" & "),M15:M100,1)=" & """#VALUE!""" & ",D15:D100)))))))"**

Comment: You can't use `"#VALUE‌​"` in a formula. If you upload a sample file then I can check what you are trying to do?

Comment: I would love to but I am not sure how to upload a file. I do not have enough reputation scores to do that I think. I tested the formula in excel and it works. BUt when I entered it to VBA, it just error me out. How would you enter such a long array formula in VBA?

Comment: I finally got it worked! I split the formula into 2 parts in code. Another question though, if I change the col A into dates. How can I modify the formula such that I want the latest date which is before today while checking the other 2 conditions? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sidd, I answered my own question! Thank you so muchhh for your help! I wish I can give you thumbs up but I don have enough reputation points. You made this so much easier! Thanks!